# Data not received by Controller from Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

My `Service` looks like

```
app.service('SupportService', function ($http, $q, $timeout) {
    var data = {result:[]};
    var getData = function() {
        $http.get('/rest/report/logs')
            .then(function (response) {
                      data.result = response.data.result;
                      console.log("received logs:" + JSON.stringify(response.data.result));
                  });
    };

    getData();

    return {
        data: data.result
    };
});
```

and in my controller, I do

```
var init = function () {
    $scope.logs = SupportService.data;
    console.log("logs = " + $scope.logs);
};
init();
```

When I run this, All I see on console is

```
logs = 
received logs:[{"lastUpdated":"1430433095000","fileName":"java_pid1748.hprof","size":"2826611251","location":"/logs/java_pid1748.hprof"},{"lastUpdated":"1430862157000","fileName":"processor-debug.log","size":"910693","location":"/logs/processor-debug.log"},{"lastUpdated":"1430861106000","fileName":"processor-debug.log.1","size":"10242519","location":"processor-debug.log.1"},{"lastUpdated":"1430862156000","fileName":"processor-error.log","size":"1015578","location":"/logs/processor-error.log"},{"lastUpdated":"1430861106000","fileName":"logs","size":"204","location":"/logs"},{"lastUpdated":"1430862154000","fileName":"error.log","size":"2420","location":"/error.log"},{"lastUpdated":"1430862149000","fileName":"output.log","size":"71","location":"/output.log"}]
```

As you could see `logs` are empty, how to I have it wait while data comes from `SupportService`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `$scope.logs = SupportService.data;` that is happening instantly - before your `$http` call is completed. You need to wait for the `$http` call to complete *then* extract the data. Generally the best way to do this is to return the promise that the `$http` creates:

```
app.service('SupportService', function ($http, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
             return $http.get('/rest/report/logs');
        };
    };
});
```

And wait for the promise to resolve in your controller:

```
var init = function () {
    SupportService.getData().then(function(response){
      $scope.logs = response;
      console.log("logs = " + $scope.logs);
    }
};
init();
```

Comment: Thanks, I would keep this in mind for next time. This worked well for me